# Java, Maven + Jenkinsfile - Cannot find classpath

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

I've got a weird one. I'm running a series of Java tests via Maven locally using the command line successfully:

```
LeveneS@WS3748 MINGW64 /h/Coding/workspace/[MY-PROJECT] (initalCommit)
$ mvn surefire-report:report test site
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---< [MY-PROJECT] >----
[INFO] Building [MY-PROJECT] 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ...etc...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.ExampleTest

40 Scenarios (40 passed)
91 Steps (91 passed)
0m0.322s

[INFO] Tests run: 131, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.01 s - in com.example.ExampleTest
```

I want to run this in Jenkins using multi-branch pipeline; so I've created a Jenkinsfile as such:

```
pipeline {
  agent { docker { image 'maven:3.6.1' } }
  stages {
    stage('Installation') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn --version'
        sh 'mvn install'
      }
    }
    stage('Run') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn surefire-report:report test site'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run this in Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
+ mvn surefire-report:report test site
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---< [MY-PROJECT] >----
[INFO] Building [MY-PROJECT] 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ...etc...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.ExampleTest
No features found at [classpath:com/example]

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.442 s - in com.example.ExampleTest
```

It looks like it can't find my classpath... but it works locally, so I can't see why it would fail on Jenkins; in any case; here's my POM File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>[MY-PROJECT]</groupId>
  <artifactId>[MY-PROJECT]</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>cucumber.api.cli.Main</argument>
                        <argument>--plugin</argument>
                        <argument>json:${project.build.directory}/cuke-results.json</argument>
                        <argument>--glue</argument>
                        <argument>com.example</argument>
                        <argument>--strict</argument>
                        <argument>${basedir}/src/test/java/com/example</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using the exec-maven-plugin like that?  What does ${basedir} resolve to on your jenkins build agent?

Comment: @Ardesco - It was recommended via HipTest.
And IDK what ${basedir} resolves to.

Comment: @Ardesco - looks like it's `/home/jenkins_slave/builds/workspace/ion-test-automation_initalCommit`

Comment: Next question is, does `/home/jenkins_slave/builds/workspace/ion-test-automation_initalCommt/src/test/java/com/examplei` exist?

Comment: @Ardesco - I don't know; it's a dockerized container in a company Jenkins that I don't have full permissions to view.

Comment: If I'm reading your POM correctly you are effectively using a hard coded path to specify the directory that your ExampleTest file resides in.  I'm guessing that the hard coded path that is generated on Jenkins is pointing at the wrong directory location.

Comment: @Ardesco - That's possible...

Comment: @Ardesco - I removed exec-maven-plugin and moved the Glue connections to the JUnit start test file:

`@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src//test//java//com//example//WIP", glue={"classpath:com/example/stepDefinition"})
public class ExampleTest {
}`

Which seems to have worked

Comment: excellent, I was trying to find a good example showing Glue, but I couldn't find one  :).  You should be able to use `src/test/java/com/example/WIP`.  Java should translate the / to the relevant file path separator for the host OS.

Comment: @Ardesco - it doesn't like single slash... The double slash works, so I'll keep it.

Comment: fair enough, good luck with it.

Comment: @Ardesco - Thanks :D

Comment: It appears the command is trying to generate the report (`surefire-report:report`) before it actually runs the tests (`test`). On your local machine, this 'works' because the report is being generated with data from the _last run_ of the build - so likely doesn't include any changes made. Try switching the order of the goal and phase and see what happens.